# How to increase nodes count in AWS EKS when using fargate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I deployed a EKS cluster with Fargate in AWS. And there are already 4 nodes in the cluster. When I deploy more deployment to the cluster, I got below error:

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  23s (x21 over 28m)  default-scheduler  0/4 nodes are available: 4 Too many pods.
```

It seems that the cluster is reaching 4 nodes limits. How can I increase the node count?

Comment: For which Namespaces did you setup the Fargate Profile and in which Namespaces do you want to deploy?